# Run the WebApp and API side-by-side for executing e2e tests

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, continuous-integration, automated-tests

I have a SPA and a REST Api in a single repository in different .csproj. When I want to debug the app, I have to launch both the SPA and the Rest API manually using dotnet run command (or IIS Express in VS). Even if the codebase is totally isolated between the webapp and the api, it wasn't necessary to split the repository. Because even if they are on a totally different codebase, the front-end is hardly binded to the API.

The SPA and the API are hosted in different domains locally :

- A vue.js .Net Core SPA hosted on https://localhost:5000 (in production
  app.mysite.com)
- A .Net Core 3.1 API Rest hosted on https://localhost:5001 (in
  production api.mysite.com)

Now, I would like to run automatic end-to-end tests on the WebApp using any e2e testing framework (Maybe TestCafe or whatever...). For automating the tests before deployment, I am using Azure Devops CI.

Here is my current CI process :

Build

- API project build
- API project unit test
- WebApp project build
- WebApp project unit test
- Packaging into artifacts both the API & WebApp

Release (Staging) - Automatic after build

- Executing database migrations, etc...
- Publish API & WebApp to staging Azure App Service

Release (Production) (Manual)

- Executing database migrations, etc...
- Publish API & WebApp to production Azure App Service

I've set up the API as following, to make it uses a fake database for testing purpose when in "Test" environment :

```cs
if (Environment.IsTest())
{
  var serviceProvider = new InMemoryDatabaseRoot();
  services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase("MyDb", serviceProvider));
}
```

Now I would like to know if it exists a single npm command for launching the webapp and the API side-by-side in test environment and when both servers are ready, launching e2e tests. In every e2e tests frameworks docs, I haven't found a way to achieve this. In most use cases, the tests are only executed on the webapp.